# InAppBrowser not redirecting to organisations login page

Tags: redirect, ionic2, inappbrowser, yammer

I am trying Yammer client side OAuth Authentication. i am using the URL of format:

```
https://www.yammer.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=https://localhost/callback?type=mobile&response_type=token
```

In InAppBrowser its showing Yammer login page, when i entered my email id, its trying to take me to my organizations login page. here its failing, i mean its not redirecting from yammer login page. its showing activity indicator and stuck there.

when i open the same url in mobile browser its redirecting and working fine. so, the issue is with InAppBrowser.

Any idea on how to resolve it?

ref: clinet-side flow in https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/oauth-2

Comment: Is your redirect URI really localhost?

Comment: actually not, anything is fine for me, as i only need auth token. is it a problem because of the redirect_uri?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @malcubierre its long back sorry I forgot how I have solved that.

Answer (score 0):

At the very end of the documentation that you linked to is this sentence:

> App authentication is handled by verifying that the redirect_uri is in the same domain as the Site URL you specified during app registration.

The localhost URI you specify here won't match. I would first try changing that URI to something that matches the Site URL for your app.

Comment: any idea what will be the url for a cordova mobile app?

Comment: You would have set it when you registered your app at Yammer. If need a reminder, you should be able to find your registered application here: https://www.yammer.com/client_applications

Comment: https://mobility.myorg.com/?type=mobile&oauth=true as my redirect url. still the same issue. its not redirecting to my organisations login page. is the redirect url is correct?

Comment: Are you able to login with the Yammer iOS app? What email address are you trying to login with?

Comment: yes iOS app is working fine. I was using InAppBrowser plugin for loading the yammer auth url. i think issue with InAppBrowser as redirection from yammer login page to myorg's login page is not happening in mobile. when i tried in browser through ionic serve, it worked and the page was launched. logged an issue with apache: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12548

Comment: Ah, ok, I'm not very familiar with Cordova. Were you able to work around your issue then by using a different browser in your app?

Comment: problem here is that, if we open it in browser from my app, i will not have control and i cant close it once Auth is done. it has to be done through InAppBrowser only upto my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

In ios inAppBrowser, I able to get the redirection from url Load start event. In the android inAppBrowser I able to get the redirection from url Load stop event.